# Add animation to panorama

Tags: javascript

I am using Panolens to create a custom Tour. I want to achieve a walkthrough effect(Zoom in and fade out) while switching from one PanoramaImage to others. Is there a way to achieve to do it? I am new to three.js and having a hard time to achieve this.

I added this but not working,

```
myInfospot.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    this.hide();
    var tweenScale = new TWEEN.Tween(this.parent.scale)
        .to({ x: -1, y: 4, z: 4 }, 500)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out)
        .onUpdate(function (nVal) {
            this.parent.scale.set(nVal.x, nVal.y, nVal.z);
        }.bind(this))
        .onComplete(function (e) {
            window.viewer.setPanorama(targetPanorama);
        })
        .start();
}.bind(myInfospot));
```